# How to determine which DateTime is greater or less than the other

Tags: flutter, dart

How it should work:

Make sure that **today** is between **2020-April-01(timestampValidFrom - firebase timestamp format)** and **2020-April-05(timestampValidTo)**.

I need like this query.

1)

```
timestampValidFrom <= today >= timestampValidTo
```

or

2)

```
 .where('timestampValidFrom', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.now())
 .where('timestampValidTo', isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.now())
```

I have tried to fix this solution, but it does not work.

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime yesterday,tomorrow;

yesterday = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day); // today 12.00.00
tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day +1); //tomorrow 12.00.00

if(yesterday.isAfter(snapshot.data[index].timestampValidFrom.toDate())
    || snapshot.data[index].timestampValidFrom.toDate().isBefore(tomorrow) 
    && yesterday.isBefore(snapshot.data[index].timestampValidTo.toDate())
    || snapshot.data[index].timestampValidTo.toDate().isAfter(tomorrow)) {
    // show widget
} else {
    //emplty widget
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`DateTime.compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html) to perform greater-than-or-equal-to or less-than-or-equal-to checks:

```dart
var today = DateTime.now();
var isValid = today.compareTo(timestampValidFrom) >= 0 &&
  today.compareTo(timeStampValidTo) <= 0;
```

You can define `operator <=` and `operator >=` on `DateTime` as extensions to make this comparison easier to read. [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) does this for you:

```dart
import 'package:basics/basics.dart';

...
var today = DateTime.now();
var isValid = today >= timestampValidFrom && today <= timestampValidTo;
```

Comment: example, `timestampValidFrom` is **today, 13:01** and **now date(system date) is today, 14:00**. this promotion is not showing, right? but this promotion should be shown. same logic for `timestampValidTo`

Comment: @BloodLoss I don't understand.  Are you saying that this doesn't do what you want?  If it's not working, then you should double-check that your 13:01 and 14:00 times are in the same time-zone.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [difference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) method.

```dart
final yesterday = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day); // today 12.00.00
final tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day +1); //tomorrow 12.00.00

int diffInDays = tomorrow.difference(yesterday).inDays;
if (diffInDays == 0){
    //custom code
    print( "same day");
} else if( diffInDays > 0 ) {
    // custom code
    print("tomorrow is greater ");
} else{
    // custom code
    print(" yesterday is less" );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check whether the current date is between the promotion start date and end date, if yes show the promotion else hide it.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime beg = snapshot.data[index].timestampValidFrom.toDate();
DateTime end = snapshot.data[index].timestampValidTo.toDate();
if(now.isAfter(beg) && now.isBefore(end)){
  print('show promo');
} else{
  print('remove promo');
}
```

It won't include the start & end date. For including the start date, check the following if statement:

```
if((now.difference(beg).inMinutes >= 0 || now.isAfter(beg)) && (now.isBefore(end) || now.difference(end).inMinutes <= 0)){
  print('show promo');
}else{
  print('remove promo');
}
```

Comment: this type is timestamp in firebase. from date is like `today, 13:01` and now is `today, 14:00`. this promotion is not showing right?

Comment: @BloodLoss: Check my updated answer, it includes the start-date.